# PHP date_create_from_format using with object giving bool(false) error

Tags: php, time

I am trying to use the PHP `date_create_from_format` on an object so I can use the `diff()` function to calculate the number of days from when the record was created to today (whenever that is looked at)

If I echo `$job->created_date` I get something like 2021-2-27 10:05:00

I started with:

```
$created = $job->created_date;
$date_now = date('Y-m-d');
$job_posted_date_difference = $date_now->diff($created); <<< the error shows on this line
echo $job_posted_date_difference.$difference->d.' days';
```

but I get a fatal error `Call to a member function diff() on string`

So....... I thought that it could be a formatting of the initial date issue and then I tried

```
$created = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d', $job->created_date);
$date_now = date('Y-m-d');
var_dump ($created);
```

But the dump shows - `bool(false)`

How do I fix this properly? I looked at a number of other SO issues and they seemed to really range from the dates being in the wrong order( I tried both ways) to the formatting issue .

Comment: `2021-2-27 10:05:00` is not `Y-m-d`, `$date_now = date('Y-m-d');` does not return a DateTime object so ->diff wont be there

Comment: I had taken this from this example - https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_date.asp. Then what is the php equivalent of MYSQL CURDATE()

Comment: https://3v4l.org/aU4XQ

Comment: @lawrencecherone thank you I understand what was wrong now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and if you want to calculate days from two dates

then you can use

```
$ceated_date = "2021-2-27 10:05:00";

//create a date object of created date and get timestamp.
$t1 = (new DateTime($created_date))->getTimetamp();

//create a date object of now and get timestamp.
$t2 = (new DateTime("now"))->getTimestamp();

//this will give you days
$day_diff = floor(($t2 - $t1) / 86400);
```